# Access latest file in repository with gradle

Tags: build, gradle, artifactory

I've created a task that can extract local .tar files (which I previously manually downloaded from Artifactory) as a test. How can I reference the files when they are on Artifactory from my gradle script? Should I just use the server path? All I've done with gradle is basic stuff and haven't worked with repositories.

I'd also like to perform a certain action based on whether the file has changed since I last ran the script, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to create a new `configuration` for your TAR file. In my example I gave it the name `myTar`. In the repositories closure you define the URL to your Artifactory repository and reference the TAR file as dependency in the `dependencies` closure. When running Gradle it will download the file for you and put it in your local repository. As I read you already created a task that extracts the TAR file. I created a task named `extractMyTar` which references your downloaded TAR file by its configuration name and untars it into a local directory.

```
configurations {
    myTar
}

repositories {
    mavenRepo urls: 'http://my.artifactory/repo'
}

dependencies {
    myTar 'your.org:artifact-name:1.0@tar'
}

task extractMyTar << {
    File myTarFile = configurations.getByName('myTar').singleFile

    if(myTarFile.exists()) {
        ant.untar(src: myTarFile, dest: file('myDestDir'))
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to try that out at the moment, but I appreciate your help. I do have a question though, in the dependencies part, the path in myTar has to be the full path to the file? or the path after what I declared as the repository URL above? Is 1.0 a version I have to specify ?

Comment: I'd recommend you read the chapter on [dependency management](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html). That will explain it all. It's not the full path to the file. It's group ID, name and version you uploaded your artifact to Artifactory with. The version 1.0 is just an example.

Comment: I got it to work thanks to your help. To complement, do you know if its possible to do a certain action if the dependency was updated? something like if (myTar.wasUpdated) { run some code }

Comment: That is usually determined by the version of the dependency. Before uploading a newer version of the file then bump up the version number. Alternatively, make it a SNAPSHOT version. For SNAPSHOT artifacts the version # doesn't change. Whenever you upload a new version its hash will change. Gradle will detect that and download the latest version. In your extraction task it might make sense to delete the existing exploded file structure. Otherwise, you'll have to think of some versioning strategy as well.

Comment: what does the << mean in the extract task?

Comment: The left shift operator means the same as `doLast`. Please be aware that the operator has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed with Gradle 5.0. You should use `doLast` instead.